# How do I show $L \not\in \widehat{(l^1)} $?

Tags: measure-theory, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $l^\infty$ be the space of all real bounded sequences equipped with supremum norm. Let $S$ be the shift operator defined on $l^\infty$ by $(Sx)_n=x_{n+1}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $x \in l^{\infty}$.

I proved that by using Hahn Banach theorem that there exists $L \in (l^\infty)^*$ such that

i) $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n \leq L(x) \leq \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n$

ii) $L(Sx)=L(x)$

I also proved that $l^\infty \cong (l^1)^*$, how do I show $ L \not\in \widehat{(l^1)} $?

Can anyone give some hint for the last part?

[image]

Comment: What does the hat mean?

Comment: I suspect that part of the problem here is that $(\ell^1)^*$ doesn't *literally* equal $\ell^\infty$. You can show that they're isometrically isomorphic, and the answer to your question likely depends on what this isomorphism is. If your isomorphism is what I think it is, then your question boils down to showing there is no $(y_n) \in \ell^1$ such that$$L(x_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n y_n$$for all $(x_n) \in \ell^\infty$.

Comment: @copper.hat The hat means the standard embedding of a normed linear space into its second dual. Specifically, if $x \in X$, then $\hat{x}$ is the functional on $X^*$ taking $f \in X^*$ to $f(x)$. The set $\hat{X}$ is the subspace $\{\hat{x} : x \in X\}$ of $X^{**}$. To say that $\hat{X} = X$ is to say $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: I defined the map $L : l^\infty \rightarrow l^*$ by $L(x)(y)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n y_n$ where $y=(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^1$.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, you need to show that no $(y_n)_n \in \ell^1$ exists so that
$$L(x_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n y_n$$
holds for all $(x_n)_n \in \ell^\infty$. Suppose this were the case, and consider $e^m = (e^m_n)_n \in \ell^1$, defined by $e^m_n = \delta_{mn}$ (i.e. the standard basis). Note that $e^m_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, so $L(e^m) = 0$. But then,
$$0 = L(e^m) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^m_n y_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n\delta_{mn} = y_m,$$
hence $(y_n)_n$ must be the $0$ sequence. But, $L$ doesn't send every sequence to $0$ (e.g. the constantly $1$ sequence), so no such $(y_n)_n \in \ell^1$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

If $ L \in \widehat{(l^1)} $ then there exists $(a_n) \in l^{1}$ such that $\lim \inf x_n \leq L(x)=\sum a_nx_n$ for all $x=(x_n) \in l^{\infty}$. Taking $x=e_k$ we see that $1 \leq a_k$ for all $k$. But then $(a_n) \notin l^{1}$.